# sparql how (1.7/2 = 0.8428572) can be correct?

Tags: sparql

I have a query that produces:
[image]

where `0.9` and `0.8` are float type.

But when I make average aggregation. I get this:
[image]

#### Update 1

This is my code

```
select distinct ?item
#?ratingValue
(AVG(?ratingValue) as ?averageRatingValue) 
{
       values ?user {bo:ania}
    ?anotherUser a ?d .
        ?anotherUser rs:hasRated ?rating .
     ?rating rs:aboutItem ?item .
     ?rating a rs:Likes .
     ?rating rs:ratesBy ?ratingValue .
      filter (?user != ?anotherUser)
}
group by ?item
```

Comment: Is it a possibility that the values `0.8` and `0.9` is truncated? I.g. if it in reality could be `0.8234...` or something alike.

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the average rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess (which I do, since we don't have access to your data or your query), I'd say that you're averaging over more than just two values, which could easily happen if your ratingValue is already coming from some kind of aggregation/grouping.

For instance, when I run

```
select (avg(?x) as ?avg) {
 values ?x { 0.8 0.9 }
}
```

I get 0.85.  But

```
select (avg(?x) as ?avg) {
 values ?x { 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9  }
}
```

gets me 0.84.  If you add in a few more terms, and have to deal with floating point imprecision, you could easily get some other values.

Comment: oh okay maybe because of the distinct thing? (when I remove the distinct and make it just select without an aggregation i get (7 lines)